# what is Enlist=false means in connection string for sql server?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, ado.net

I am a beginner with .net. I faced issue with the following error

> "The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests working on this transaction.".

i read somewhere in the blog .i appended my connection string with `enlist=true` and the issue was resolved.

**Note**: i am upgrading my DB from sql server 2005 to sql server 2008R2.

Please help to understand the importance of using enlist.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Enlisting is user for [Distributed Transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720033(v=vs.71).aspx)

> The Connection object will automatically enlist in an existing
>   distributed transaction if it determines that a transaction is active.
>   Automatic transaction enlistment occurs when the connection is opened
>   or retrieved from the connection pool. You can disable auto-enlistment
>   in existing transactions by specifying `Enlist=false` as a connection
>   string parameter for a SqlConnection, or OLE DB Services=-7 as a
>   connection string parameter for an OleDbConnection.

**Note**   The Connection must be `open` before calling `EnlistDistributedTransaction`.

Here is an example for you with [`Enlist=False;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633341/connection-using-enlist-false-does-not-close-after-being-manually-enlisted-in-di)

Answer (score 5):

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172070(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> The ConnectionString property supports a keyword, Enlist, which
>   indicates whether System.Data.SqlClient will detect transactional
>   contexts and automatically enlist the connection in a distributed
>   transaction. **If Enlist=true**, the connection is automatically enlisted
>   in the opening thread's current transaction context. **If Enlist=false**,
>   the SqlClient connection does not interact with a distributed
>   transaction. The default value for Enlist is true. If Enlist is not
>   specified in the connection string, the connection is automatically
>   enlisted in a distributed transaction if one is detected when the
>   connection is opened.

Comment: This seems to be misleading, in that Enlist=false means the connection won't enlist in any ambient transaction (such as from a TransactionScope), whether or not it is distributed.   So setting Enlist=false would only work if you never needed TransactionScopes at all, which seems a very undesirable thing.