# Azure SQL does not support elastic transactions

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, msdtc

Recently we are migrating our SQL Server database to Azure SQL database  but it  does not support transactions even we build our web application to target .net framework 4.6.1 as per the guidance given in Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-transactions-overview). We are using MSDTC transactions in the same database not shared database, is the reason? Am I  missing any configuration settings here?

Actually, I don't get any error but the transaction doesn't work and no rollback happens, allows partial data save.

When I check the transaction at Azure SQL DB, it shows no transaction happening at the time.  The same code works well with my local database, I am able to see the current transactions running and transactions rolled-back when it is not committed.

Following are the details.

I have set target framework to 4.6.2 at VisualStudio And updated the same in my web.config.
Sample code:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    using (var aoContext = new AOCrowdFundEntities())
                    {

                        //do somthing

                        aoContext.SaveChanges();

                        throw new Exception();
                        scope.Complete();
                    }

                }
```

When I  have a breakpoint before throwing the error and run the following query to see the current transaction, it shows an empty list.

Even when I throw the error without committing the transaction, the data are saved in Azure DB. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL Database does not currently support distributed transactions as explained in this [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-distributed-transaction-transact-sql). To use the Microsoft Distributed Transactions Coordinator (MSDTC), deploy your database on a SQL Server instance running on a virtual machine.

Comment: I agree Azure SQL Database not yet support MSDTC transaction on   T-SQL,  but they are supporting System. Transaction in the name of elastic transaction.  See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-transactions-overview

Answer (score 0):

I missed to remove a setting (Enlist=false) from DB connection string which was introduced to support MSDTC transaction. See below to know more details,

[what is Enlist=false means in connection string for sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35716193/what-is-enlist-false-means-in-connection-string-for-sql-server)